# How can I shut down a RedShift cluster from the command line?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift, aws-cli

I want to shut down an AWS RedShift cluster through the command line, to avoid cluster charges in night time when no one use it.

I tried to search for the command, but didn't find it.

Anyone has idea about it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Sounds like you're looking for [delete-cluster](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/redshift/delete-cluster.html)?

Example usage that takes a final snapshot:

```
aws redshift delete-cluster --cluster-identifier mycluster --final-cluster-snapshot-identifier myfinalsnapshot
```

You can use this snapshot with [restore-from-cluster-snapshot](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/redshift/restore-from-cluster-snapshot.html) to restore when you need to set the cluster up again:

```
aws redshift restore-from-cluster-snapshot --cluster-identifier mycluster-clone --snapshot-identifier my-snapshot-id
```

This is the most approximate way to perform a "shut down" operation as you've described -- you cannot start and stop RedShift like an EC2 instance, so you must destroy and recreate it instead.  This will at least allow you to stop and start operations on your data.

Comment: sounds reasonable to do this daily to save costs on a 500Gb Db? Or the data transfer/ time_to_restore costs will offset the potential savings?